# What do I do when ffinding a backwards integral of an integral that produces a negative number?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am not sure how to handle this question involving definite integrals.

> Suppose $$\int^4_{1}f(x)dx=6, \int^2_{1}f(x)dx=6, \int^4_{3}f(x)dx=1$$
>
> Solve:
> $$\int^3_{2}f(x)dx=$$
>
> $$\int^2_{3}(6f(x)-6)dx=$$

I can tell that $\int^3_{2}f(x)dx=-1$ since $\int^4_{1}f(x)dx=6$ and $6+x=6$ only if $x=-1$.

However, my assumption is that if  $\int^3_{2}f(x)dx=-1$ then $\int^2_{3}f(x)dx=1$.

If that is the case, then it seems like $\int^2_{3}(6f(x)-6)dx=6(1)-6=0$.

However, this is wrong.

What did I get wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct apart from the fact that
$$\int_3^2(-6)dx=\int_2^3(6)dx=6(3-2)=6$$
so the correct answer should be $6(1)+6=12$.

Comment: Thank you, that was confirmed as the correct answer, could you please tell me why is $\int^2_{3}(6f(x)-6) = 2\int^2_{3}(-6)dx$?

Comment: It's not. $$\int_3^2(6f(x)-6)dx=6\int_3^2f(x)dx+\int_3^2(-6)dx=6(1)+6=12$$

Answer (score 1):

Your only mistake is the last $-6$ sign which should have been a positive $6$ making the final answer $12$ instead of $0$ .

Comment: Thank you, why does the sign of the last 6 change?

Comment: The integral is from 3 to 2 which makes it negative times negative to generate positive 6

Comment: Why doesn't it affect both sixes so the definite integral becomes equal to $-6(1)+6=0$?

Comment: you have already answered your own question for the first part, it is 6(1)